# Google maps api - kml load (php)

Tags: php, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to load my kml files ( hosted on my server) dynamically,

this example works

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://myhost.pt/perc/perc1.kml',{suppressInfoWindows: true});
```

but I need something like

```
<?php $var= ' users/hash/perc1.kml'; ?>
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://myhost.pt/<?php $var; ?>',{suppressInfoWindows: true});
```

so I need to concat the url, I really have no idea if I can do this

I hope to have been elucidative..
if somebody could help me i'm thankful

Answer (score 1):

you almost have it,

change

```
<?php $var; ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```